# How to fix the donut chart size in c3js

Tags: angularjs, charts, c3.js

I am unable to fix the donut size in c3js. Whenever the no of labels int the legend and the length of the labels increase, I need to increase the chart size to accommodate them. But this affects other charts with less no of labels in the legend. To be consistent, I use the same chart size for all the donut charts I show in the page. But the size of donuts are all different according to the legend labels and it does not look good. Any suggestion on how to fix the donut size regardless of the legend labels. I am using padding to place the legend on the right of the chart.

Below you can find the code to generate the chart :

```
<c3chart bindto-id={{id}} chart-data="piePoints" chart-columns="pieColumns" padding-left="0" padding-right="300" padding-top="0" padding-bottom="0">
                <chart-size chart-width="400" chart-height="300" />
                <chart-donut width="40" expand="false" show-label="true"></chart-donut>
                <chart-legend show-legend="true" legend-position="right" />
                <chart-tooltip show-tooltip="false"/>
            </c3chart>
```

In the fiddle below, I have 3 charts generated by c3js. I want to fix the size of the chart but it can be seen that the donut size varies according to the legend.

https://jsfiddle.net/anu23/qzew784d/2/

Is there way to keep the donut size fixed regardless of the legend label length and the no of labels in the legend.

Comment: This is an angular (or similar) directive and not plain c3.js code. You need to provide either the implementation of this directive or better a version which generates the chart with plain JavaScript (provide the configuration object). Then, you should provide a working minimal example in a jsFiddle.